# Convert A List To Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I've implemented a search option using Linq that works fine as follows:

```
string[] str = txtSearch.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');

var con = (from c in context.Customer
           join d in context.CustomerType on c.CustType equals d.ID
           where str.Any(t => c.CustName.Contains(t))
           select new { c.CustomerID, c.CustName, c.CustAddress, d.Type }).ToList();

grdDetails.DataSource = con;
grdDetails.DataBind();
```

But I heard about `Dictionary` that works very well for lookup rather than `List`. So I've tried to do the following but doesn't get any data to show:

**Edited:** I've edited the following for `Dictionary` but it seems like if I work with **EF**, I have to loop through the `List` to get with `Dictionary`. By the way, there are no relation between the keys in both dictionaries. So I guess, there would be no lookup though tried in another way. It works but want to know if it's a good practice.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Customer>();
dictionary.Add(1, new Customer() { CustomerID = 1, CustName = "AT", CustType = 1 });
dictionary.Add(2, new Customer() { CustomerID = 2, CustName = "AT-2017", CustType = 1 });
dictionary.Add(3, new Customer() { CustomerID = 3, CustName = "Jackson", CustType = 1 });
dictionary.Add(4, new Customer() { CustomerID = 4, CustName = "Anderson", CustType = 1 });

var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<int, CustomerType>();
dictionary2.Add(1, new CustomerType() { ID = 1, Type = "Active" });

//dictionary.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains("AT")).ToList();

var con = (from c in dictionary
           join d in dictionary2 on c.Value.CustType equals d.Value.ID 
           where str.Any(t => c.Value.CustName.Contains(t))
           select new { c.Value.CustomerID, c.Value.CustName, d.Value.Type }).ToList();

grdDetails.DataSource = con;
grdDetails.DataBind();
```

I was trying to follow a tutorial that converts a `Dictionary` into `List` at the end. But I am not sure about it why it has done so. So I would like to know if the above way is the perfect one to do the search using `Dictionary`.

**Note:** I've used `Dictionary` in the console application and I understood how it works. But little bit confused to do the joining using `Dictionary`.

Comment: In your first code block, why are you joining `CustType` to `ID`?  `on c.CustType equals d.ID` That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: It seems like you're dealing with EF or some type of Linq to SQL provider, in which case your Linq code is just translated to SQL and the type of container wouldn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @juharr. Yes! I am using EF for it. So what you meant there is no need to use the `Dictionary` or not required for the above case? I was wondering if I could implement the above with `Dictionary`. Just trying to clarify.

Comment: First off, joining 2 **empty** dictionaries will always return empty result. Second, once you have a dictionary, there is no benefit of using LINQ join because the dictionary itself is well suited for fast lookup, and LINQ join will not use it, so basically it will be the same if you have used lists, arrays or just LINQ to Objects queries.

Comment: I've edited my answer @Ivan Stoev. See if this is somewhat nearer the way I am looking for. Thanks for the comment. The `Dictionary` worked and getting data with the above edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your query is still a list so I'm surprised the con.Values compiles.

Also, the second code example is running a query on two initialized but not populated dictionaries, so no data is a correct result.

I suspect your first code example is better if it is going against the database. It will use the database's optimization to run the query and return the results. There really wouldn't be any advantage of loading all that into memory first then running a query.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeS. I am doing it for database operation or regarding database. I can understand the query is ok to work with. But curious to know if I could make it with `Dictionary`. By the way, I am using EF.

Comment: If you want a dictionary created from your query, there is a ToDictionary method that takes in Expressions that will form the key and the value for each entry. You would replace your ToList() with this.

Comment: I've edited my answer @MikeS. The `Dictionary` worked and getting data but see if this is somewhat nearer the way I am looking for. Thanks again for the comment.